# Alter Keras model for validation step

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a model that differs during the training and inference. More precisely, it is a SSD (Single Shot Detector) that requires additional DetectionOutput layer to be added on the top of its training counterpart. In Caffe, one can use the 'include' parameter in the layer definition to turn layers on/off.

But what should I do after having defined and compiled the model, if I wish to run validation after each epoch (inside a callback)?

I cannot add DetectionOutput during the training, since it is not compatible with the input to the loss.

I also would like to avoid creation of DetectionOutput layer somewhere inside callback or a custom metric, since it requires sensible hyperparams and I would like to keep the model creation logic inside the dedicated module.

In the following example code model is created for inference, DetectionOutput layer is present. So the evaluation runs just fine:

```
model, _, _ = build_model(input_shape=(args.input_height, args.input_width, 3),
                          n_classes=num_classes,
                          mode='inference')
model.load_weights(args.model, by_name=True)

evaluation = SSDEvaluation(model=model,
                           evaluator=PascalDetectionEvaluator(categories),
                           data_files=[args.eval_data])
metrics = evaluation.evaluate()
```

But this callback does not work properly because during the training model does not have DetectionOutput:

```
class SSDTensorboard(Callback):
    def __init__(self, evaluator, eval_data):
        self.evaluator = evaluator
        self.eval_data = eval_data

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.metrics = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        evaluation = SSDEvaluation(self.model, self.evaluator, self.eval_data)
        metrics = evaluation.evaluate()
        self.metrics.append(metrics)
```

What would be the proper (pythonic, keratonic etc.) way to run the training as usual, but perform validation step on the altered model with the same weights? Maybe, having a separate model for validation with shared weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the headless (without DetectionOutput) model for training, but provide a model with the top layer to the evaluation:

```
def add_detection_output(model):
    # make validation/inference model here

...
evaluation = SSDEvaluation(model=add_detection_output(model),
                           evaluator=PascalDetectionEvaluator(categories),
                           data_files=[args.eval_data])
```

Avoid using the training model inside the callback, let the evaluation object hold the reference to the validation model:

```
class SSDTensorboard(Callback):
    def __init__(self, evaluation):
        self.evaluation = evaluation

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        metrics = self.evaluation.evaluate()
```